# I encountered an error while attempting to request subscription function in-app purchases with react-native-IAP library

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-iap

Based on the below information, it appears that the error is related to a server-side issue with the Google payment service itself rather than an issue with my code or setup.

**Error:**

```
{
  "code": "E_DEVELOPER_ERROR",
  "debugMessage": "Server error, please try again.",
  "message": "Google is indicating that we have some issue connecting to payment.",
  "responseCode": 5
}
```

**Package:**

```
"react-native-iap": "^12.10.5",
```

I have created the product ID from the google play console and passed it in the `requestSubscription` function after that I am getting this error.
if anyone sorted this issue please help or provide me guidance to solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Please update your subscription code with the provided code, and replace 'skus' with the corresponding SKUs.

```
getSubscriptions({ skus: ["testpro123"] })
    .then((value) => {
      requestSubscription({
       subscriptionOffers: [
       {
         sku: "testpro123",
         offerToken:
         value[0]["subscriptionOfferDetails"][0]["offerToken"],
       },
    ],
   })
   .then((value) => console.log(value))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
   })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

ref:[Github issue](https://github.com/dooboolab-community/react-native-iap/issues/2492)